# Can anyone help me understand why I can't seem to get a value out of my form using flask and wtf?

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Route

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
# from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import logging
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler
from forms import *
import os

@app.route('/wallthickness')
def wallthickness():
    form = WallThicknessCalc()
    return render_template('forms/wallthickness.html', form = form)
    
@app.route('/result', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def result():
    form = WallThicknessCalc()
    diameter = ''
    diameter = request.form.get('PipeOD')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template ('pages/result.html', form = form, diameter = diameter)
```

---

This is the python file where the form code resides.

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, PasswordField, FloatField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, EqualTo, Length


class WallThicknessCalc(Form):
    PipeOD = TextField('Pipe Outer Diameter', 
                        validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    DesignPressure = TextField(
        'Design Pressure', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    DesignFactor = TextField(
        'Design Factor', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    SMYS = TextField(
        'Specified Minimum Yield Stress', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    Calculate = SubmitField(
        'Calculate', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
```

---

This is the form with input fields.

```
{% extends 'layouts/main.html' %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="/result" method=[POST] class="form-group">
              <fieldset>
              <div>
              {{ form.PipeOD.label(class="form-control-label") }}
              {{ form.PipeOD(class = "form-control form-control-lg")}}
              <br>
              {{ form.DesignPressure.label(class="form-control-label") }}
              {{ form.DesignPressure(class = "form-control form-control-lg")}}
              <br>
              {{ form.DesignFactor.label(class="form-control-label") }}
              {{ form.DesignFactor(class = "form-control form-control-lg")}}
              <br>
              {{ form.SMYS.label(class="form-control-label") }}          
              {{ form.SMYS(class = "form-control form-control-lg")}}
              <br>
              {{ form.Calculate(class = "form-control form-control-lgbtn btn-primary")}}
              </div>
              </fieldset>
                
            </form>
        </div>
            
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am trying to display the result here:

```
{% extends 'layouts/main.html' %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>The mininmum wall thickness is {{ diameter }} mm</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have been unable to retrieve the values entered into the form fields. I get the error TypeError
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's probably tripping you up is [CSRF Protection](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html). In particular, the lack of

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}
```

in your form.

Also, you're subclassing `Form`, which is deprecated in favor of `FlaskForm`, but that's unrelated. It's also recommended practice do do

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    ...
```

Comment: I have added 
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
Got rid of the error message.